# Need symbols for libopenal1 package

Tags: sound

We've got some crashes in `libopenal.so.1.13.0` and unfortunately this package was built without symbols. I've tried downloading `libopenal1-dbgsym` (appending `-dbgsym` works for most packages once the ddebs repositories are configured) but there is no `-dbgsym` package available for `libopenal1`. Apparently the package was built in a way that doesn't work well with `pkg-create-dbgsym`.

Who should I talk to about getting this corrected? Canonical? The developers of `libopenal1`? We could try building `libopenal1` from source and distributing our version with symbols but that doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The building of ddebs is down to the build system and the Debian packaging.

The openal-soft source package is in universe so is community maintained. If this is fixed in Ubuntu, then it would primarily fall to the [MOTU team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU). Any fix would best be forwarded up Debian as well, since ddebs apply to Debian too. In Debian, the appropriate person is the maintainer of the openal-soft package.

You should check for existing bugs in both [Debian BTS](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=openal-soft;dist=unstable) and [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openal-soft), file bugs as appropriate, and link Launchpad bugs to any corresponding Debian bug.

Providing a suitable patch directly to the Debian maintainer in a bug filed in the Debian BTS is the easiest way to get something like this fixed. Then the change will eventually arrive in Ubuntu, or you can ask MOTU to merge any fix from Debian in the meantime.